# Bamboo build YAML: Trigger build via cron on specific BitBucket Git branch only

Tags: bamboo, bamboo-specs

I have a project's code on BitBucket Git repo. At the moment Bamboo executes YAML-based Build Plan successfully with every commit, on every Git branch.

Now I want to add another trigger to let Bamboo execute build of **only** `master` branch once a week. I've tried by adding this YAML lines:

```yaml
triggers:
  - remote
  - cron:
      expression: 0 30 8 ? * WED
```

BUT: Bamboo seems to take code from that Git branch he executes the last build on. So for instance, if I commit code to branch `foo` the afternoon before Wednesday morning,
Bamboo executes build of code from this branch `foo` immediately after the commit, which is fine and expected. But Bamboo **also** triggers build of **this** branch `foo` at 8:30 am on Wednesday.

How do I tell Bamboo YAML file to launch build of **`master`** branch code every Wednesday morning?

Thanks

Christian

PS: Bamboo version `8.1.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I've found a solution:

```
branch-overrides:
  - master: # Modification of steps/triggers to apply with Git master branch builds only!
      triggers:
        - polling: # Launch job every wednesday morning
            cron: 0 30 8 ? * WED
```

Unfortunately, this modification of `bamboo.yml` **itself** does **not** trigger a build, nor does it launch the job on next wednesday! At least according to my experience, you have to commit "something else" (like source code files) to get Bamboo recognize your wish to launch build of `master` branch every wednesday morning.

Christian

**Update on wednesday, 2022-05-25**: **Doesn't work** for unknown reasons, I think cron expression should make Bamboo launch build this morning, but it doesn't happen.

Weird.